# Carbon::isoFormat doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, datetime-format, php-carbon

since, laravel uses `now()` as the helper function for Carbon class, I tried this

`dd(now('GMT+5:45')->isoFormat('x')))`

but it returns laravel's bad method call exception saying that

`Illuminate\Support\Carbon::isoFormat does not exist.`

All I want is to convert date and time to `time string` just like `strtotime()` function

what sould I do now ?

Comment: just use format function on carbon instance

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are using a version of Laravel which is lower than `5.8` where it includes *Carbon 1*, thus, `isoFormat()` is **not included** since it's part of *Carbon 2*.

So you may go with the option of using `formatLocalized()` but please note it's using a [different](https://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) placement pattern than `isoFormat()`

My advice to you is to upgrade to `Laravel 5.8` if you want to use `isoFormat()`

If you would like to stick with your current version of Laravel and keep using `formatLocalized()` then you need to do the following:

1. In one of your service providers, let's say AppServiceProvider, within your register() add: `Carbon::setLocale($this->app->getLocale());` this is will localize `->diffForHumans()` **only**.
2. Help carbon by setting the php `setLocal()`, where it will use the already installed Locales in your machine to make sure your OS (Linux/Mac) has the desired local installed: you may check so by typing `locale -a` if it's not showing then run: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` a simple GUI will appear to select the desired local by hitting the *sapce* button then *enter*, select the default Locale then.
3. If you just installed the desired locales then **please make sure to restart your php-fpm service:** `systemctl restart php7.3-fpm.service`
4. Use localized methods, in your case: `->formatLocalized()`. i.g: `->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')`

Answer (score -2):

You can use `format()` function from `Carbon`.

```
now('GMT+5:45')->format('y-m-d');
```

`'y-m-d'` could be replaced with format that you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

EDIT: 
Or if you want to use `isoFormat()`,

You can use `Carbon::now()` instead of `now()`.

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->isoFormat();
```

This issue happens because `now()` is a Laravel helper and it returns `Illuminate\Support\Carbon`.

Comment: @VincentWasteels The question specified all he wanted is convert date and time to `time string`. It doesn't specify if it has to be in ISO format

Comment: Mmmm you are right, someone with rights should update the question heading then